# Insert page breaks between report groups with two-sided printing

Tags: crystal-reports, page-break, formula-editor

In group expert options I have set Keep Group Together, which makes sure a new page is set.

With two-sided printing enabled, how can I make sure that a new group always forms on a new sheet of paper? Can this be done in the formula expert? Is there some way of checking if the page I'm on is even or odd and insert a page from there? Just asking leading questions because I'm not familiar with what is possible with Crystal's formula editor.  BTW, This is Crystal XI Enterprise Server.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can do this with the `onfirstrecord`, `pagenumber` and the `onlastrecord` keywords.

On the group header section "New page before" formula...

```
not onfirstrecord //so every group (except the first) starts on a new page
```

On "New page after" formula...

```
//to keep the group from starting on even page but make sure the last page is not blank
remainder(pagenumber, 2) = 1 and not onlastrecord
```

Answer (score 7):

Open the Section Expert screen. Select Report Header and check "Suppress (No Drill-Down)".  Then select in the group header select the group you want to page break and check "New Page Before".

Answer (score 3):

This Works fine if I need Page Break on one Group. How do I do if Page Break on Multiple Groups?

I found answer..
Using `Next(Field)` or `Previous(Field)`, I added below condition and worked fine.

In Next Page Before formula:

`Not onFirstRecord and ({table.field} <> previous({table.field}))`

Answer (score 0):

hi IronicMuffin i understand you question. the answer is versy simple but more effetcive.

- step 1: Include dataset or database expert into your crystal report
- Step2: In the outside surface of the report area right click and goto report and goto group expert
- Step3: add the which field you include the group that time the bottom of the window options will appear
- Step 4: click the option and agian goto 2nd tab of the option.
- step 5: finally check(check=true) check box of Repeat Group header on each page other check box or put uncheck

Comment: I notified you about this a short while ago: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)