# Insert page break for each month in crystal report

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am working on crystal reports in c#.
while printing sales report I want to insert a page break for every new month.

Comment: [How can I insert page breaks between groups in Crystal Reports with two-sided printing?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704296/how-can-i-insert-page-breaks-between-groups-in-crystal-reports-with-two-sided-pr

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the property that.
select g`roup section -> select option tab -> insert 1 in the text box of the filed name new page after 1 visible group`
Thus your problem should be solve.