# Heading repeated for every record in the table

Tags: crystal-reports

My report handles several Members based on a 4-column Members table.
[image]

For some reason, each Member is being repeated on the report for every record in the table. How can I configure this such that every member has a separate set of records?

In other words, repeating should consider `"MeberName + Test"` as one single unit.

Answer (score 1):

Add a Group section based on your Member field. Then right click on that Group and select Section Expert. Check the `New Page Before` option to configure the behavior you asked for.

Additional help:
[Insert page breaks between report groups with two-sided printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704296)

Comment: what happened, please share your screen and step which done

Comment: Also you need to exercise after page and before page new line property as per your requirement.

Comment: You'll need to move everything from detail section to group header section.