# Crystal Report 2021

Tags: crystal-reports

Consultation, I have a report that is generated in batches, but I need that when finishing a record on an odd page it leaves me a blank page to start again on an even page.

Can someone give me an idea on how to correct this issue?

Comment: Please, provide a bit more details to the question.

Comment: The report generates a batch of documents, some of which are only for one page and others for more pages and what we need is to add a blank page in the report when a record ends on an even page, since it is necessary to leave the other Blank page and in the future to be able to print all the documents and these are separated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the documents separated, you just need to make a group that identifies a single document and then in the 'Section Expert' of the group footer, in 'Pagination' tab, check 'New page after'.

But i suspect you are trying to print with both sides of the page and you want to start a new document in a new page, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1704399/4436459)